# GUI Emacs does not show up in Open With menu

Tags: emacs

Emacs is installed with `brew cask install emacs-mac`, which also moves it to Applications folder. Works fine. However it is not listed in Open With menu. If I choose Other... from Open With dialog, then select Emacs, it works fine.

I had many entries for many Emacs versions in Open With dialog before, then tried cleaning up the entries with trashing com.apple.LaunchServices.plist and restarting, after uninstalling all other gui Emacs versions.

How do I put Emacs back on Open With menu?